# Check for completion on the firebase js .forEach method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that there's a completion handler for `.set` and `.update`, but I was wondering if there was something like that for `.forEach`.

For example, something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('kid').orderByChild('date').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(kid) {

    }, function(error) { //This is where the error is thrown

    }
});
```

If this isn't possible, is there a workaround?  I just need a function to call once the `.forEach` method is done running.

P.S. My function is actually stated in another file, but I just call it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is a synchronous javascript function. Simply add a line after the function.

Comment: It says I can't accept the answer yet, but that did it!  I guess I didn't think it could be that simple :)

Comment: @SamuelUyemura Also, you can only pass one function as argument to .forEach. To catch errors use a try catch statement instead :)

Comment: Ok, I'll try that!